# Load a Data from a file into Table using Hbase MapReduce

Tags: java, mapreduce, hbase

I need to load data from a File which is located in HDFS and load it in Hbase table using Hbase Map Reduce.I have the csv file which conatins only values of column Qualifier as follow:

Now in my Hbase table how can i load this values from mapReduce program. And how the RowId will be auto generated.

```
    Class:


    public class SampleExample {

          private static final String NAME = "SampleExample "; //class Name

          static class Uploader extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> 
          {
            private long statuspoint = 100;
            private long count = 0;
            @Override
            public void map(LongWritable key, Text line, Context context)
            throws IOException {
              String [] values = line.toString().split(",");
                      /* How to read values into columnQualifier and how to generate row id */
         // put function-------------------
                               try {
                context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(row), put);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
              if(++count % statuspoint == 0) {
                context.setStatus("Emitting Put " + count);
              }
            }
          }
      public static Job configureJob(Configuration conf, String [] args)
          throws IOException {

                                   }
        }
```

Error:

```
12/09/17 05:23:30 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201209041554_0071_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable, recieved org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1019)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:691)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
        at com.hbase.Administration$Uploader.map(HealthAdministration.java:51)
        at com.hbase.Administration$Uploader.map(HealthAdministration.java:1)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Can any one please help me, i am not able to figure, how we read values into qualifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String stringLine = line.toString();
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "\t");`

Put put = new Put(key.get());
put.add(family, column1,stringTokenizer.nextToken().getBytes());
put.add(family, column2,stringTokenizer.nextToken().getBytes());
put.add(family, column3,stringTokenizer.nextToken().getBytes());
put.add(family, column4,stringTokenizer.nextToken().getBytes());

try {
    context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(row), put);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I want RowId values to be auto generated when reading data .   Put put = new Put("8".getBytes()); I have now idea why u used "8".getBytes().

Comment: sry .  i miss-understood .
i that case  Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(key.get+1));
This will give you unique rowIds .

Comment: Hi, i have tried with Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(key.get+1)); in my code, i can see only 2 rows stored in my table. please check the above code which i have edited.How can i make rowId auto generted

Comment: Please check my job configuration code, i have updated my code

Comment: i)Please check the time stamp of the rowId , see if its shwoing todays date& time ,
ii) comment job.setNumReduceTasks(0); and try again , 
it Should work

Comment: Hi i tired by commenting  job.setNumReduceTasks(0); and executing it in server i got the above exception,please check the the error updated

Comment: Hey i have added another ans , please check

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much. I removed comment for  job.setNumReduceTasks(0); and added byte [] RowId = Bytes.toBytes(key.get()); in code and passed rowid to put method. then it started working. I didnt tried with reducer ().

Answer (score 0):

please change your map & reduce as following . 
In Map work on row id only , and pass this worked rowID and the Line(as it is ) to the reducer

```
map{
  byte[] row=Bytes.toBytes(key.get());
  try {
            context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(row),line);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
```

Reduce changes

```
@Override     
reduce (ImmutableBytesWritable row , Text line ){
String stringLine=line.toString();
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer=new StringTokenizer(line, "\t");

Put put = new Put(key.getBytes());
put.add(family, column1,stringTokenizer.nextToken().getBytes());
put.add(family, column2,stringTokenizer.nextToken().getBytes());
put.add(family, column3,stringTokenizer.nextToken().getBytes());
put.add(family, column4,stringTokenizer.nextToken().getBytes());
try {
    context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(row), put);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Please make appropriate changes in your according to the above code .
The Exception is coz , when we a +ve number of reducer , then map  function can't write to the table(or use put object), so the context.write(writable,put) is being shifted to reduce which has the table-name ,where the final output need to be wrote .
Hopefully this should work out . else i will write a working code of same input file and paste it here

Answer (score 0):

Hi just remove +1 in put command as follow Put put = new Putkey.get()); and remove the comment of
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);  then it surely works